# Connection to Azure Service Bus using Java Spring Application - Timeout

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-java-sdk

I have written a client which tries to connect to Azure service bus. As soon as the server starts up i get the below errors and i receive no messages present at the queue. I tried replacing the sb protocol with amqpwss, but it dint help.

```html
2020-05-25 21:23:11 [ReactorThreadeebf108d-444b-4acd-935f-c2c2c135451d] INFO  c.m.a.s.p.RequestResponseLink - Internal send link 'RequestResponseLink-Sender_0480eb_c31e1cc239bf471e811e53a30adc6488_G51' of requestresponselink to '$cbs' encountered error.
com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ServiceBusException: com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.amqp.AmqpException: The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 60000 milliseconds and is closed by container 'LinkTracker'. TrackingId:c31e1cc239bf471e811e53a30adc6488_G51, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2020-05-25T21:23:10
at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ExceptionUtil.toException(ExceptionUtil.java:55)
at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.RequestResponseLink$InternalSender.onClose(RequestResponseLink.java:759)
at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.amqp.BaseLinkHandler.processOnClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:66)
at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.amqp.BaseLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:42)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
at com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:491)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.amqp.AmqpException: The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 60000 milliseconds and is closed by container 'LinkTracker'. TrackingId:c31e1cc239bf471e811e53a30adc6488_G51, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2020-05-25T21:23:10
... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar issue opened in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues/243)

> what you posted here is the trace, not the error. Yes, the service
>   closes idle connections are 10 minutes. The client traces it and
>   reopens the connection. It is seamless, doesn't throw any exceptions
>   to the application. That can't be your problem. If your sends are
>   failing means there may be another problem, but not this one.

As i see the second line it is about the timeout of 6 secs, can you check the [troubleshoot page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-troubleshoot) if it helps. Also [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/ce261f33-8a72-44f0-bb60-af9f32e50194/servicebus-over-amqpqpid-client-closes-consumer?forum=servbus).

> we recommend adding "sync-publish=true" to the connection url

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read about sync_publish but looks like its at the sending end, But i am just trying to receive messages from a service bus queue. And after this log there is a message which says "Closing connection to host". And i don't receive any messages being sent from the other end. Do i have to get this value included at the end which is sending messages?

Comment: yes try that way, wherever you are using this piece of code

Comment: I edited the above logs can you check once (first line). I tried connecting with another queue, on server startup, it tries to register a message handler on the queue. But for this one, nothing of this sort happens.